# Terminal Prompt showing scary message

Tags: macos, network, mojave

I run om-my-zsh and my prompt usually says

> ```
>    gregg@Gumby $
> ```

where Gumby is the name of my Mac.

Today it said

> ```
>    gregg@Michaels-iPhone $
> ```

I was not connected to any iPhone. All sharing features in system preferences sharing are off.

what is going on?

Comment: not a dupe. I never connected to any iPhones and was not on the net so the question is where the name came from not the fact that it can be changed but rather how was it changed to a random user's iphone if I was never connected to that user's iphone

Comment: Check if `Michaels-iPhone` is in the list of Preferred Networks in your Network preferences.

Comment: don't know any Michaels. Have never paired with a friend's iPhone. There is no Michaels-iPhone in my preferred networks

Comment: It will be rather difficult to figure out the source of this *after* it happens, especially if you rule out the usual options (iPhone (inadvertently) used as hotspot, or iPhone connected to Xcode). If you follow the recommendations in the answer to the original question, do the changes stick or does it revert back to "Michaels iPhone" after a reboot/a few days?